# iOS - AudioServicesPlayAlertSound not working on ipod?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ringtone, audiotoolbox

I cannot get `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` to make the ipod beep - I know it cannot vibrate, but its suppsoed to beep atleast.

It compiles fine, added the audiotoolbox and just calling that line, and nothing happens. The sound is on of course.

Any idea on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may give you some more info?

```
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1649698?start=0&tstart=0
```

I had the same problem, but it worked fine a few days later without any changes??

PS. Stupid i Know but make sure the volume is on and up when your testing...